# [dotCover]DotCover missing coverage for the referenced source DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, dotcover

I just started using dotCover,been almost two days but no results. I have a test project 'A' with all the TCs based on unit framework,I have added the code assembly as reference assembly in my project assembly 'B' When I build and run the test cases,everything is executed as expected. What I'm getting is the coverage of my test project 'A' instead of the whole coverage i.e baseline code. like my TC-1 is passed,TC-2…TC-N is passed,and coverage against every TC in % with no reference to underline code.
While going through solutions provided in a couple of other posts I have tried the following options.
1)Adding PDB files of  assembly 'B' in the Debug folder of the test project 'A'.
2)Enabling/Disabling the switch unchecking "match with current project structure" 
3) Adding the src project in the test project.
4)Using the src project and adding the Test Project as standalone application[nunit] and executing.
In all the above cases,I got the same results.
Coverage of the code of my Test Cases,no results for actual code :(

Plz help to sort this out,this has already taken enough of my time ..:'(

Comment: Same issue for me. Exe and pdb is copied correctly. In the code where coverage is not reported, I see the highlights in red even though my tests for that code were executed and passed.